# Data Relationships, Data Filters and Automation Studio

Tags: marketing-cloud, relationships, data, automation

I've created a User-Initiated Email that is using a Data Filter. That Data Filter is using a Data Relationship. When I try to fire an email send via Automation Studio, the job sits there running for 30 minutes and then fails. Automation Studio simply says "Error has occurred" which isn't very helpful at all.

Here is a bit more about the setup -

Triggered Send Data Extension contains all the users that have created an account on the website and have had the initial welcome email sent to them. There is a field called CustomerId which is a number field and has a default value of 0 if not supplied.

A normal Data Extension which has a primary key called CustomerId, EmailAddress and contains the last purchase date and total.

The Data Relationship maps the CustomerId between the 2 DEs.

The Data Filter has the logic:
PurchaseDate is equal to today AND AccCreationDate is not empty.

Does anyone have any insight as to why this might be failing?

Comment: Are you able to run the data filter and populate a filtered data extension without any issues?  You may want to reach out to support (help@exacttarget.com) as they should be able to pull more details on the error.

Comment: Thank you Jeremy, once I looked at the filtered data extension it became pretty obvious. The problem was my filter was using the wrong source data extension. Now the automation is working perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Jeremy's comment I was able to easily debug the problem I as having with Automation Studio.

If you encounter a problem where everything seems like it is setup correctly, created a filtered data extension to see what data is being pulled and that you have the columns that you are expecting to collect.

I had the wrong source data extension as the source which caused the filter to fail.